# Configure UDP for Remote on Akka.net

Tags: akka.net

```
akka {
    actor {
        provider = remote
    }

    remote {
        dot-netty.tcp {
            port = 8080
            hostname = localhost
        }
    }
}
```

Sample configuration for tcp and it works fine

Any help on how to connect with UDP would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

At this point UDP connections are not supported. The major constraints are:

1. Akka requires, that the messages from one actor to another must be passed in the same order, as they were send. UDP doesn't guarantee ordering by itself.
2. UDP doesn't offer message redelivery, increasing the ratio of lost messages.
3. UDP datagrams are strictly limited in size, so big messages that doesn't fit into a single datagram, would require additional logic for splitting/combining before and after send.

These requirements are usually solved by network protocols build on top of UDP, like [Aeron](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/wiki/Protocol-Specification) or [QUIC](https://www.chromium.org/quic). However, since there are no reliable .NET implementations for both client and server for those, they are not yet available in Akka.NET.

Comment: but akka.net documentation says that UDP implementation is possible ?

Comment: You can build any protocol on top of actors - example here could be Akka.IO and Akka.Streams.IO, which offers layer of abstraction on top of .NET sockets - but that doesn't mean they has been implemented.

Comment: but if I have to use UDP or customised protocol, then on the server side also I have to have an actor ? OR can I use the client side as actor model but on the server side machine software just listening to queries from my custom client ?